# BizTalk hosts delay when used for the first time

Tags: biztalk, hosts

Is a delay the first time the BizTalk hosts are used?

Is there a way to ensure that they are always "kept alive" and ready for any first requests that come in?

Comment: Did my answer below answer your question?

Comment: To be clear, this behavior is endemic to all .Net applications, not just BizTalk.  The vase majority of times, this turns out to be a non-issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not the BizTalk host as such, but yes, there can be a delay the first time a web service or Orchestration is called to load a the DLLs needed.

If we want to keep it warm, for a web service you can set up a schedule adapter or scheduled task to call the web service to keep it alive.

To keep on Orchestration loaded it memory, the was a method of pinning it so it wasn't removed, by settings in the bts config file.  The other method would be to have some sort of keep alive message going to the Orchestration, which would then just discard that message.